# UIButton Inversion Concurrency issue

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, uibutton

I have a question about inverting colors of a uibutton. I am trying to change between text color and background color; however, when a user tries to press it very quickly the colors stop inverting. I believe this is an issue of concurrency.
I have tried using locks and operation queues. Anyone have any suggestions?

Heres my code

```
  func invertStartButton(){
    let currentBackGroundColor:UIColor? = self.startButton.backgroundColor
    print(currentBackGroundColor)
    objc_sync_enter(currentBackGroundColor)
    defer{
        objc_sync_exit(currentBackGroundColor)
    }
    self.startButton.backgroundColor = self.startButton.titleLabel?.textColor
    print(self.startButton.backgroundColor)

    self.startButton.setTitleColor(currentBackGroundColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to **disable** the button during changing:

```
@IBAction func invertButton(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.enabled = false
    // invert
    sender.enabled = true
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but seems to still have the same result

Comment: That is virtually impossible.

Comment: it has something to do this line     let currentBackGroundColor:UIColor? = self.startButton.backgroundColor, so i decided to just hard code the colors and have a bool values to fix the inverting. This answer did not work because it was not a button problem but more a setting color problem

Comment: Fair enough, a polite up-vote would still be in order.

Comment: I would but im still under 15 post. I promise to come back to update it =D

Answer (score 0):

Problem had to do with instance variable. So, in order to fix this I used a two hard coded codes with a bool value for the switching